# Javascript: concatenating "000" to a number and string

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I have these epochs:

```
1586998726 and "1586998726"
```

I need to turn both to:

```
1586998726000 and "1586998726000"
```

Can't really figure out. Help appreciated.

Comment: `+` works fine for concatenating strings. For the number, just multiply by 1000.

Comment: And in modern JS, use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). `\`${yourval}000\``, done. ("modern" with a grain of salt, everything except IE11 has had support for it for _years_ now)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yeah but one needs output to be number and other needs string i guess by posted output format

Comment: Your epoch value should be a number, wherever you got that string from, you should just immediately cast it to a number at the edges of your system, and never let bad data like this flow through your inner layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have

```js
var epochInteger = 1586998726;
var epochString = "1586998726";
```

You can do:

For the **number**

```js
epochInteger * 1000 === 1586998726000;
```

For the **string**

```js
epochString + "000" === "1586998726000";
```

To do conversions between them

```js
epochInteger.toString() === epochString;
Number(epochString) === epochInteger;
```

But note that these conversions work in both cases

```js
epochString.toString() === epochString;
Number(epochInteger) === epochInteger;
```

So **in general** you could use something like

```js
var modifiedEpochInteger = Number(epochAnyType) * 1000;
var modifiedEpochString = modifiedEpochInteger.toString();
```

and you'd get the result in both types, no matter where you started!